# Kinematics Question AP Physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A motorcycle officer hidden at an intersection observes a car driven by an oblivious driver who ignores a stop sign and continues through the intersection at constant speed. The police officer takes off in pursuit 1.80 s after the car has passed the stop sign. She accelerates at 4.4 m/s2 until her speed is 116 km/h, and then continues at this speed until she catches the car. At that instant, the car is 1.5 km from the intesection.
>
> How long did it take for the officer to catch up to the car?

This question is from a homework question that I have in AP Physics (where collaboration is allowed). I've solved it out, but since I don't have the answer key, I wanted to check with someone to make sure that my math is correct. And if there is an easier way of solving this?

I understand that there are multiple ways of doing this.
116 km/hr = 32.222222 m/s
Total time = Time police officer takes to reach vf (ta) and time it traveled at vf (tb)

My method:
Police Officer's displacement: vf = vo + at
32.222222 = 0 + (4.4)(t); t = 7.323233
distance traveled (1500) = (Integral from 0 to 7.32323 of 4.4t dt) + 32.2*tb
Solve for tb: tb = 42.89
Total time = 7.323232 + 44.89 + 1.8 = 52.0133

Comment: As the school year progresses, you will want to be careful regarding sig figs.  The problem statement has a maximum of 3 sig figs, but some of your numeric equations have 8 sig figs in them.  This will normally lead to loss of points on the AP test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, I also derived the same values - however just for ease I will just show you my method of reaching to the values. Before I begin, I would like the reader to be aware that I am taking the first 2 decimal digits of the answers just for the ease of calculation and so that the reader can understand it with ease.

First we will ignore the delay of 1.8 seconds as it is not needed currently, however we will pay particular attention to the acceleration so first we begin by creating the police (motorcyle officers) motion functions:

$\boxed{a(t) = 4.4\:m/s^2 \\ v(t) = \int{a}\:dt  = 4.4t\:m/s \\p(t) = \int{v}\:dt = \frac{4.4t^2}{2}=2.2t^2 \:m}$

As you see the motion functions are very well defined and serve as purpose for our use for the first part of the question. Now that we are aware of this lets progress on wards.

Now, the police accelerates to 116 km/h and since it is not in our desired metrics of meters and seconds we will do so, by simply converting 116 km/h into m/s by: $\frac{116 * 1000}{3600} = 32.22 \: m/s$ Now that it  is in our desired units we can calculate the time for the acceleration to reach velocity of 32.22 m/s which can be done by placing the value into velocity function to get:
$$
 32.22 = 4.4t \\t = \frac{32.22}{4.4} \\ t = 7.32 \:s
$$

Now that we know how long the police had to accelerate to get to the velocity of 32.22 meters per second we can calculate how far the police traveled whilst accelerating which can be given by our position function, however in that we will pass in the time of 7.32 seconds (the time taken to accelerate to 32.22 m/s or 116 km/h):
$$
   p(7.32) = 2.2(7.32)^2 = 117.88 \: m 
$$

As the police traveled 117.88 meters and since we know that the police caught up to the dangerous driver at 1.5 km - 1500 meters - we can then know the police has yet to travel $1500 - 117.88 = 1382.12$ meters till the police catches up to the driver. Now let us continue on wards, in this we will need to construct new functions as the police stopped accelerating and is now in pursuit of the driver at a constant velocity, so acceleration function is not needed, anyhow:

$\boxed{v'(t) = 32.22\: m/s \\ p'(t) = 32.22t \: m}$

Now that we have got this, we can now plug in the remaining distance we ought to cover into the position function and then rearrange the equation to get the time when the driver is caught:
 $$ 1382.12 = 32.22t\\ t = \frac{1382.12}{32.22} = 42.89 \: s$$

Now finally we have calculated all the times required and have successfully solved it now all is left to do is to add the times and then throw out the final answer which can be:

$$t = 1.80 + 7.32 + 42.89 = 52.01 \: s$$

For those who are still reading, I'll just explain that 1.80 is the delay before police reaction, then 7.32 is the time took to accelerate to 116 km/h (or 32.22 m/s) and then 42.89 was the time took at that speed to then finally catch up with the criminal.

**Extra calculations for love of physics**

If we really wanted to impress the teacher - you could perhaps even calculate the average velocity of the dangerous car driver for the fun of physics, it can be done by first calculating the time in which the driver passed the sign till the time he was caught (1500 meters) and the time is quite straight forwards $t = 52.01 - 1.80 = 50.21$

Now that we know that we can simply use $v = \frac{d}{t} = \frac{1500}{50.21} = 29.874527\: m/s$

In terms of kilometers per hour it is: $107.548297\: km/h$ or miles: $66.8274135$ miles.

This is actually not that fast in terms of highways\motorways as a result we can even suggest that this incident did not happen in highways\motorways but rather in street roads or something similar.

*Note: This will not gain any extra marks (at least not in my experiences) but its just to impress your teachers and spur on love of physics!*

Answer (score 1):

Yupp, your maths seems correct. I got the same answer. 
I do not think there is another way of doing this. You could try and graph the motion of the two cars, $v$ vs $t$ and you know the area under graph is 1500m, try and find the time?
But I immediately thought of the method you used.